# based bitcoin address decentralized IP address, Abolish ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

THE IDEAL PATH
What if we replace the controlled and surveilled IP addresses with new internet addresses that are based on bitcoin address? These addresses will inherit all bitcoin address features, i.e., they will be purely decentralized, secure, future-proof, robust, anonymous, unhackable, controlled by no single authority and many more.

Is it just a dream? For now. If this could be true we would be changing the internet as we know it.

- bitcoin address + bitcoin DNS, access to bitcoin domain

win10 network adapters : Enter the bitcoin address
Wi-Fi  DHCP Static : Enter the bitcoin address

---

IPv4 and IPv6 are centralized. They are controlled by national companies, etc.

[image]

Try to Google “Who controls IP addresses?” You’ll promptly get “IANA: the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority.” IANA is the top authority behind IP address allocation and assignment. There are five different regional internet registries (RIR) with jurisdiction under the IANA.

As a matter of fact, as an individual or a normal internet user you cannot request IP addresses directly from IANA or one of the five RIRs, but only from internet service providers, such as the services offered by mobile or telecom operators.

- True decentralization, no official singular Foundation, Committee, Corporation, or entities in permanent unitary control of the protocol.

Comment: This reads like a call to action, not a question. If this was meant as a question, please clarify what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just a dream?

Yes.

1. Internet routers route IPV4 and IPV6. They won't route other protocols at the [internetwork layer](https://superuser.com/a/449747/52492). You wouldn't be able to use existing Internet network infrastructure.
2. Bitcoin addresses are impractical as network addresses. Firstly because such use would compromise privacy. Secondly because their random distribution implies there would be the problem of gigantic routing tables to be solved somehow.
3. We already have Tor.
4. Protocols like HTTPS and others that encapsulate data in TLS etc already provide end to end protection against surveillance of IPV4 & IPV6 contents (if not against observation of occurrence and volume of communications)
5. If big companies like [Google decided that they had to continue using not only IPV4/IPV6 but also TCP/UDP](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lmL9EF6qKrk7gbazY8bIdvq3Pno2Xj_l_YShP40GLQE/edit#heading=h.h3jsxme7rovm) - it suggests that using anything other than TCP/UDP over IPV4/IPV6 on a network the scale of the Internet is infeasible without truly gigantic levels of support.
6. Other networks exist but I suspect they don't offer any special benefits of the sort you seek. One example might be a mesh of radio links. There are problems of scale, both geographically and in terms of capacity and latency.

Comment: As far as I know, many national ISPs have blocked TOR export ip.
You are using a bridge to link tor, some countries tor nodes are not available! The reason is that ISPs block the ip of tor outlets

Comment: Also of note: [yggdrasil](https://yggdrasil-network.github.io/) and [i2p](https://geti2p.net/en/)